# How to install gcc-4.8 on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: gcc, versions, 19.04

Today updated Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04 and found that gcc-4.8 and related packages were removed. But I need them to build soft for my work. How could I recover them and their dependencies?

Comment: An "extra **non-PIE**" `gcc, g++ -4.8.4` is available for  all Ubuntu versions, 14.04 .. 19.** : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing ... Provides `/usr/local/bin/{gcc48, g++48}`. ... Or you can add like `deb [URL] bionic universe main` to /etc/apt/sources.list ... to install the 18.04 `g++-4.8`

Comment: @KnudLarsen No, no, no, and no, and no! I will not grab random binaries from a random cloud. Also, I don't feel OK at all mixing different distro releases, i.e. if you're on 19.04=disco, it's better to not mix that with "bionic" packages.